# How to slice a PCAP file efficiently?

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, tshark

I am trying to slice a large PCAP file (3 GB) using tshark in Ubuntu.
The code below is what I am trying to do:

```
tshark -r dia5_20Jan17.pcap -Y '((frame.time >= "2017-01-20 10:32:00") && (frame.time <= "2017-01-20 18:44:00"))'  -w 1.pcap
```

The problem is the waste of memory RAM:

The code is using 95/95% of memory (8GB). Is there a better way of slicing the PCAP file? I tried Python too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tshark isn't the best tool for the job. I've had good experience with [libtrace](http://research.wand.net.nz/software/libtrace.php) ([github link](https://github.com/wanduow/libtrace)), which gives a nice toolbox for handling capture files. Specifically, in your case, the [tracesplit](https://github.com/wanduow/libtrace/wiki/tracesplit) tool.

Note that most of their examples are with a capture format called erf, not pcap. But they [support pcap](https://github.com/wanduow/libtrace/wiki/Supported-Trace-Formats) files, you just have to specify it.

The equivalent tracesplit command would be something like:

`tracesplit --starttime=1484908320 --endtime=1484937840 -compress-type=none pcapfile:dia5_20Jan17.pcap pcapfile:1.pcap`

Comment: How can I convert  frame.time >= "2017-01-20 10:32:00" in timestamp?

Comment: @AnadiKrsnadas Using any UNIX time converter. For instance: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: tracesplit --starttime=1484908320 --endtime=1484937840 -compress-type=none pcapfile:dia5_20Jan17.pcap pcapfile:1.pcap
-> error: Floating point exception

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) to split up capture files.  For example:

```
editcap -A "2017-01-20 10:32:00" -B "2017-01-20 18:44:00" infile.pcap outfile.pcap
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it just now, but my guess is that the memory footprint is mostly caused by the TCP dissector tracking connections etc. If you create a profile where you disable all dissectors you do not need (and since you're filtering on frame meta info only that's probably **all of them**) you might save a lot of RAM.

The way I would do this is

1. start Wireshark
2. create new profile
3. use "Analyze" -> "Enabled Protocols" -> "Disable All"
4. close Wireshark
5. run tshark, specifying the new profile with the "-C" parameter

As I've said, I haven't tested this for your case, but I use reduced dissection settings a lot when carving packets from pcaps. It's faster, gives less errors, and can save RAM.